# Can you decompose a wave approximately?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fourier-transform, decomposition, wavelet

I have data which looks like composition of sine waves.
[image]

I need to decompose it to fewest possible sine waves that would give me tolerable error.

The picture is of a half-period. Each half-period would be different so I need to analyze each half-period separately as if they arent related (this is empirical limitation).

The data has no physical meaning so the decomposition would not be precise ever, also there is no *energy* for proper Fourier transform.

Is there a software package (preferably in python) that can find a function that decomposes **approximately** given wave with error `sigma`? if not what would you suggest?

Comment: Depending on how you measure error, the FT will be a good candidate for the solution.  The meaning of "no energy" is obscure.

Comment: I don't think FT can do approximate decomposition though? Can it?

Comment: Pick a subset of the components, such as those with the largest coefficients.  That's the same idea as PCA.